# Multiple variadic parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
template <class ... Required>
class Base
{
    template <class First, class ... Rest>
    void bar(First f, Rest ... r)
    {
        [...]
        return bar(r...);
    }
    void bar()
    {
        return;
    }
    public:
        template <class ... Optional>
        void foo(Required ... r, Optional ... o)
        {
            [...]
            bar(r...); //separate the required from the optional
            bar(o...);
        }
};

class Child : Base<Foo1, Foo2>
{
    public:
        Child()
        {
            [...]
            foo(foo1,foo2,foo3);
        }
}
```

But the first `bar` call is receiving all the parameters instead of only the `Required` ones, and the second call is receiving none of the parameters. Did I miss something about multiple variadic parameters? Shouldn't the compiler know that `Required...` is `Foo1,Foo2` and the rest is `Optional`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I tried your code with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.3, and both of them produced the expected output.

Comment: Tried with gcc 4.6.3 and clang 3.0 via <a href="http://liveworkspace.org/code/35c5Nh$0">liveworkspace</a> and clang 3.0 shows the bug you are observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is most likely a bug in whatever compiler you are using. I tried it with gcc 4.6.3 and 4.7.2, and with clang 3.0 and 3.3, and all of them produced the expected output except clang 3.0.

Comment: I'm using Apple LLVM 4.1, Good to know it's a compiler problem, I'll update and see if that helps. Also thanks for the `sizeof...`, I didn't know about that.

Comment: There is no version 4.1 of LLVM, presumably you mean Xcode 4.1

Comment: @LukeB. By the way, the clang 3.3 was compiled from trunk last night. You'd probably have to search through their bug queue to find out when the behaviour was fixed. I hope that an update helps.